# Jquery detect user interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, jquery-animate

I have this code that scrolls the page automatically and stops the animation when the user interacts with the page. THis working properly on desktop devices but not on iphone. When the user try to scroll the page with his finger the animation doesn't stop until reach the bottom of the page. What can i do for this? Thanks!

```
$("html,body").stop().animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 2000);

// Stop the animation if the user scrolls. Defaults on .stop() should be fine
$("body,html").bind("scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup", function(e){
    $("html,body").stop();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I add this in the bind area and it works "touchstart touchmove"

```
$("body,html").bind("touchstart touchmove scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup", function(e){
    $("html,body").stop();
});
```

Comment: very clever one

Answer (score 2):

If you need only to detect it once, you can use

```
$("body,html").one("touchstart touchmove scroll mousemove mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup", function(e){
    console.log('Detected');
});
```